# when to use getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(someBean)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In spring when to use below code? what will be the effect if include below line?

```
getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(someBean)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, the answer is "never".  This is an internal Spring function, and while you *can* use it yourself, you very probably shouldn't.

You can use it to autowire dependencies into an object that you create yourself, but that's a very specialised use case that you don't need 99.99% of the time.

Comment: Can you give an example when to use this? Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I have met an usage scenario, as follows:

Specifically:I have 2 projects,p1 and p2.

p1: This project has a class A which used @Resource annotation to autowire a bean B into Spring IOC, and class A has method f() which used the atuowired bean B.

```
public class A{
@Resource
B b;
public void action() {
    System.out.println(b == null);
    b.dosth();
    }
}
```

p2: This project calls the action method of A by reflection.

```
URL url1 = new URL(jarPath); // "file:D:/jarload/test.jar"
URLClassLoader myClassLoader1 = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url1 },
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
Class<?> myClass1 = myClassLoader1.loadClass(classFullName);
Object obj = myClass1.newInstance();
// this.context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(obj); //without this,the b will be null.
Method method = myClass1.getDeclaredMethod("action");
method.invoke(obj);
```

1. Export p1 to a jar file by eclipse.
2. In p2, run the jar.

Hope it helps you!